# Externalize Spring Libraries Web Application

Tags: java, spring, websphere, tomcat7, static-libraries

Good morning @ Everybody,

i would like to know if it is possible to externalize Spring libraries. We have a lot of Applications / Webservices which all use the same Spring - libs and now we are forced to deploy our applications on a Websphere (8.5.0.1) server. Since Websphere and Classloading is a bit different than everything else i knew before ...

Well ...

The Idea is the following:

Create a mavenproject containing all Springlibraries and add this jar-file to the server. We would like to keep developing on a tomcat server and just deploy on a websphere without having to much trouble...

But if i move all my springlibs to an external file, it seems that the application cannot be loaded properly (Classloader issue?). 
So if anybody of you could give me a hint or a good suggestion, i would really appreciate that. 
And of course, if i miss a fact, why it is not possible?

Edit:
This is how my pom.xml actually looks like (a part of course) and i really, really do not like it ...

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/hibernate*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*spring*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xpp3_min*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xstream*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/antlr*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/webservices-api*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/dom4j*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/javassist*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/primefaces*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/redmond*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/sunny*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/akka*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/scala*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/scala*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/config-0.3.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/cglib-nodep*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/quartz*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/c3p0*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.3.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.9.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jettison-1.0.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but if i do it like that, add this libraries as external, my application works (but **JUST** on a Websphere, which is absolutely not my intention)

Comment: Wouldn't the Spring Libraries be part of the WAR which will contain WEB-INF/lib directory? Wouldn't that ensure that it will work seamlessly on Tomcat and Websphere ?

Comment: i exactly thought the same, but on websphere it did not work as expected. I had to create a lot of shared library on the server add tell my application that it should use this libs. Else i had a lot of conflicts in my applications. But to be honest, i work the first time with websphere .. maybe there is a way to make it work much more efficient.. but as far as i can tell, i nearly tried everything. The only thing working was to exclude *.jar files from my web.jar and add them as separate loaded libs

Comment: I don't understand why putting the Spring libraries in WEB-INF/lib in the war file doesn't work. We do this all the time, although admittedly not yet on WAS 8.5. It worked on 8.0 when we tested there, but maybe something is different in 8.5?

Answer (score 1):

try keeping the spring libraries inside the WEB-INF/lib folder as suggested by @Dhanush Gopinath and than change the classloader to parent last.

To change the classloader go in the Domain Manager console to.

Servers > WebSphere Application Servers > $Server Name > Servers Specific Application Settings

Change the ClassLoader policy to "Single" and class loading mode to "parent last". Check if this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thx, i already tried that, but then i get some exception with XML-DocumentBuilder, wrong JSF Version and it was more or less a never ending story ... which finally forced me to externalize the libraries. My Application somehow started to work, but i am sure there must be a much nicer way to do that (f.e. i have a huge list of libs in my pom.xml which should not be implemented, that is not how it is supposed to be, is it?) But i will give it  another try now .. maybe i did something wrong before...

Comment: Here you can see the errors http://pastebin.com/cALXWVbg. Any other hint? Thank You!

Comment: Hi, about the XML errors, try removing all XML related apis (xerces, xalan, etc) from your application. You should rely on WebSphere ones. About the JSF error it might be you're using a different version of JSF other than WebSphere default one. There's a way to specify this in WebSphere but unfortunately I don't remember how to do it from the top of my mind by now.

Comment: that is exactly what i tried to do and i ended up in removing a lot of libraries from my *.war.
I am also using mojarra as JSF, which actually all works fine, as long as i add them as external libraries.. But that is really a lot of effort and not really nice to look at ... 
See my edited post for more details.
But thanks for your help!